# htaccess CSP - images blocked on firefox (but working on chrome)

Tags: .htaccess, firefox, content-security-policy

I have a problem loading YouTube thumbnails on Firefox, the images are blocked while on Chrome, it works fine. On Firefox I get the error NS ERROR INTERCEPTION FAILED in the network tab from the developer tools and if I remove my CSP in my htaccess file, those images are loaded correctly.

My CSP looks like this:

```
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header set X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff”
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'        https://*.laurentwillen.be https://*.googleapis.com https://*.googletagmanager.com https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://www.google.com https://cse.google.com https://*.gstatic.com https://*.youtube.com/ https://*.mobilemultimedia.be"
Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
```

and the call to the image looks like this:

```
 <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/xSbxgNuBfR0/0.jpg" alt="youtube_preview" width="100%">
```

Do you know how I could go around this and make Firefox load those images just like Chrome?

Thanks